# How to update array's field in Mongodb with Go

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, bson

I want to change `stu1` to `stu3`

```
import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)
type Student struct {
    Name string `bson:"name"`
    Age  string `bson:"age"`
}
type Class struct {
    Id      string    `bson:"_id"`
    Student []Student `bson:"student"`
}

col := mongosession.DB("test").C("class")

stu1 := Student{"jack", "18"}
stu2 := Student{"rose", "16"}
class := Class{Id: "123", Student: []Student{stu1, stu2}}
col.Insert(class)

stu3 := Student{"lisi", "14"}
```

How do I do the update? Is it like the following

```
col.Update(bson.M{"_id": "123"},
            bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"student": ??????}})
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$set` operator and the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) :

```
err := col.Update(
  bson.M{"_id": "123"},
  bson.M{
    "$set": bson.M{
      "student.0": &stu3
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It  works. What if i don't know stu1 is the 0 field in the array, i just know the name is "jack", then how to write the update code?

Comment: `err := col.Update(bson.M{"_id": "123", "student.name": "jack"},
  bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"student.$": &stu3}})`
 
 this can work.